# Modify HTML to convert anchor links & text links to embedded youtube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML that I am wanting to automatically modify looks somewhat similar to below:

```
<div class="blob-of-text">
    <div>
        Text
        <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br>
        <a href="https://youtu.be/NTT1iNQq123" class="linkified" target="_blank">https://youtu.be/NTT1iNQq123</a>
        <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br>
        https://youtu.be/NTT1iNQq123
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm running the following code that I've found in various locations and modified to make change my html

```
html_data = $('.blob-of-text').html()

var pattern1 = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/?(.+)$/g;
var pattern2 = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)$/g;
var pattern3 = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))$/gi;

if(pattern1.test(html_data)){
    console.log("pattern 1");
    var replacement = '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    var html_data = html_data.replace(pattern1, replacement);
}

if(pattern2.test(html_data)){
    console.log("pattern 2");
    var replacement = '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    var html_data = html_data.replace(pattern2, replacement);
}
if(pattern3.test(html_data)){
    console.log("pattern 2");
    var replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img class="sml" src="$1" /></a><br />';
    var html_data = html_data.replace(pattern3, replacement);
}

$('.blob-of-text').html(html_data)
```

However, it isn't converting the anchor links and for some reason it makes the first iframe have a link containing all of the rest html...

A good example can be seen: https://jsfiddle.net/cupnabm7/6/

Comment: Try adding `m` to your regex flags for multiline matching. Also instead of using regexes to match the page HTML, you could loop through all the anchors on the page, regex match their `href`'s, and `replaceChild` the element with an iframe?

Comment: Don't use `var` when changing value of existing variable

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I can't loop because they're not always anchors, sometimes they're plain text links.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It doesn't seem to work either with var not being set and the m flag added to the regex. See: https://jsfiddle.net/cupnabm7/6/

Comment: That seems like it's happening because your regex is only finding the `href` and then replacing the `href`'s value with the iframe HTML, which won't work. Looping through all the elements might be best -- even if they're plain text links, you can do something like find all `text` nodes or `a`'s on the page and check their value/href